# How to sort a dictionary items in vim

Tags: vim

How to use sort function in vim script to sort a dictionary?. The help documentation doesn't seems to provide clear information on how a particular element in the dictionary can be sorted.

For eg: I am getting the quickfix items by calling getqflist(). How to sort this quickfix dictionary items with respect to line numbers?

Comment: The output of `getqflist()` is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your comparison function, save result of the `getqflist()` to a variable and `call sort(v, f)`

Example:

```
function! LineLessThan(leftArg, rightArg)
  if a:leftArg['line'] == a:rightArg['line']
    return 0
  elseif a:leftArg['line'] < a:rightArg['line']
    return -1
  else
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

function! KeyLessThan(leftArg, rightArg)
  if a:leftArg['key'] ==# a:rightArg['key']
    return 0
  elseif a:leftArg['key'] <# a:rightArg['key']
    return -1
  else
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

let g:a = [{'line': 3, 'key': 'd'}, {'line': 1, 'key': 'e'}, {'line': 5, 'key': 'b'}, {'line': 2, 'key': 'a'}, {'line': 4, 'key': 'c'}]
call sort(g:a, function("LineLessThan"))
echo g:a
call sort(g:a, function("KeyLessThan"))
echo g:a
```

Comment: While trying to call sort  "sort(itemsCopied, function("LineLessThan")) "after copying the quick fixlist using the statement let items = <SID>GetlistTest('', "qf") i am receiving the following error.
 E:21 cannot make changes, modifiable is off:^Isort(itemscopied,function("LinelessThan")). I even did a deepcopy of quickfixlist before calling the sort with let itemsCopied = deepcopy(items). But even this doesn't help to call sort as it shows error modifiable is off.

Comment: @Anoop `:help E21`, `:help modifiable`, try `set modifiable` or [functional programming technique](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/39.html) (calling sort on local function variable)